# Searching for / Finding non-const static variables in source code (.cpp)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and our (c++) project has grow quite a bit in last years.

Static analysis is (unfortunately) currently still work-in-progress, so I'm looking at other options to improve our code quality in the meantime. One of the issues I've stumbled across is the (ab)use of non-const static variables in some older parts of the code.

I can easily track down (non-const) static variables in classes and functions with a regex search (e.g. `^.*static (?!(const)).+$`), but I'm having a hard time tracking down non-const static variables declared in namespaces (or simply in .cpp files), e.g.

```
//Foo.cpp
#include <Foo.h>
int sharedValue = -1;

int Foo::notThreadSafeAndNotConst(int bar) const
{
    if (bar < sharedValue)
        bar = sharedValue;
    else
        sharedValue = bar;
    return bar;
}
```

So I'm wondering, is there a simple way to track down those (implicitely static) variables via e.g. a regex search, or do I need to wait for e.g. a static analysis tool to find them?

Comment: Some nitpicking: The variable `sharedValue` have [*external* linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#external_linkage), not [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#internal_linkage) which you get from using the `static` keyword.

Comment: Do you mean global variables ?

Comment: In your example, how will you 'fix' sharedValue ?

Comment: @darune In the example? Well, it depends on how the function is actually supposed to work. `sharedValue` might have been introduced as part of a hurried (and misguided) "I need to change this, but - oh - the function is const" rework - this would imply that the sharedValue should be a member and the function not const. Or it is genuinely be a value that needs to be shared across all instances of `Foo` - then it might be sensible to dependency-inject a shared object that holds the value (while also providing thread safety functions). There are a lot of possible scenarios...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right of course, though half of the time the variables are actually declared in an anonymous namespace (e.g. `namespace { int someValue = -1; }`) which turns them into internal linkage again... either way, they are (supposedly) meant to be only available only in this very .cpp file - the external/internal linkage issue is a headache for another time...

Comment: non-const static variables: this must have a single storage location in the program
Since the non-const static variables is mutable, it must be stored in an actual location somewhere, so that one part of the program can modify it and another part can see that modification. But it can't be stored in a class instance, so it must be more like a global variable.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I don't quite understand what you are trying to say here - I am aware of the properties of non-const static variables. This is why I am looking for a way to find them in the source code, so I can refactor them (depending on their purpose) into something cleaner.